# Specifying An Entry Point For Class Library Projects

Tags: c#, .net

is there's a way to specify and entry point to execute some code -namely registering some components in an IOC container- in a class library project.
I do realize I could use the PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute but is part of the system.web namespace hence it will only work with ASP.NET applications I need something that will work with a tester console application as well an MVC application

Comment: You could use a static constructor, which is guaranteed to run if your code actually accesses at least a static field of the class. But doing so is a code smell, since this is exactly the sort of thing IoC is supposed to eliminate. It shouldn't be up to your class library what ends up in the IoC container. You can provide a convenience method, but then your main executable should still call that. Some container frameworks also allow configuration files, or attributes. If you really want your library to "plug in", then that's probably what you want: a plug-in framework.

Comment: If you are really desperate then you could use a *module initializer*.  Not supported in C#, but C++/CLI, IL or a library like Fody provides one.  You'd have to be pretty desperate, few reasons to despair over a unit test.

Comment: "You can provide a convenience method, but then your main executable should still call that"  I strongly support this solution.